# Retrieving login information based on AuthenticationDomain from the SAS Metadata Server failed

Tags: sas, teradata, sas-dis

I am getting issue in SAS while executing the SAS job , getting error "Retrieving login information based on AuthenticationDomain from the SAS Metadata Server failed" My tables are in teradata server. please guide me.

Here I'm posting some piece of log file code, which I believe interpret the issue.

```
NOTE: CALL EXECUTE routine executed successfully, but no SAS statements were generated.
MPRINT(ETLS_GETPARAMETERS):  ;
MPRINT(ETLS_PROCESSTOLOOPWPM8XG):  ;
Process ID: 31002
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   options metaport = 8560 metaserver = "xxxl01010.xxxxxx.com.au";
MPRINT(ETLS_SETDEBUG):   OPTIONS MPRINT;
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):  ;
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   LIBNAME TDST1V TERADATA SERVER="xxxx8.xxxxxxx.xxx.xx" SCHEMA=IUSIT02_STG_ED_VIEW AUTHDOMAIN="Teradata 
Auth" ;
NOTE: Libref TDST1V was successfully assigned as follows: 
      Engine:        TERADATA 
      Physical Name: xxxx8.xxxxxxxx.com.XX
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):  ;
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   options comamid=TCP;
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   data _null_;
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   signon AuthDomain="DefaultAuth" noscript;

ERROR: Retrieving login information based on AuthenticationDomain from the SAS Metadata Server failed.
ERROR: Remote signon canceled.
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   run;
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      user cpu time       0.00 seconds
      system cpu time     0.00 seconds
      memory              352.59k
      OS Memory           13464.00k
      Timestamp           15/03/2017 02:39:09 AM
      Step Count                        84  Switch Count  55
      Page Faults                       0
      Page Reclaims                     9
      Page Swaps                        0
      Voluntary Context Switches        209
      Involuntary Context Switches      0
      Block Input Operations            0
      Block Output Operations           0

140                                                        The SAS System                            02:01 Wednesday, March 15, 2017


MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   data _null_;
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   if 9.4 ge 9 then rmtname = "/ remote = local";
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   else rmtname = "";
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   call execute('%syslput job_rc = &job_rc '||rmtname||';');
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   call execute('%syslput trans_rc = &trans_rc '||rmtname||';');
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   call execute('%syslput sqlrc = &sqlrc '||rmtname||';');
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   call execute('%syslput syscc = &syscc '||rmtname||';');
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   call execute('%syslput etls_stepStartTime  = &etls_stepStartTime'||rmtname||';');
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   call execute('run;');
MPRINT(ETLS_JOBWPM8XQ):   run;

ERROR: A link must be established by executing the SIGNON command before you can communicate with LOCAL.
ERROR: A link must be established by executing the SIGNON command before you can communicate with LOCAL.
ERROR: A link must be established by executing the SIGNON command before you can communicate with LOCAL.
ERROR: A link must be established by executing the SIGNON command before you can communicate with LOCAL.
ERROR: A link must be established by executing the SIGNON command before you can communicate with LOCAL.
```